# jquery mobile - custom selectmenu in persistent fixed header

Tags: jquery, mobile, header

I'm trying to use a custom selectmenu widget in a persistent fixed header (derived from demos).

First page without selectmenu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>tryout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/_assets/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">Header</div>
<div data-role="page">FooBar</div>
<script>
$(function(){ $( "[data-role='header']" ).toolbar(); });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is okay, Header and FooBar appears because the $( "[data-role='header']" ).toolbar(); line (as documentation cites the need it's presence).

Let's replace the "Header" text with a selectmenu (only body section again):

```
<body> 
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="select-custom-1">Menu:</label>
        <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
            <option value="0">Item1</option>
            <option value="1">Item2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page">FooBar</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $( "[data-role='header']" ).toolbar();
});
</script>
</body>
```

The selectmenu is showing up but does not work (does not react to click).

Removing the $( "[data-role='header']" ).toolbar(); call the page div hides the header.

Removing the $( "[data-role='header']" ).toolbar(); call and the page div entirely the selectmenu is working!

It seems that the $( "[data-role='header']" ).toolbar(); call kills the functionality of selectmenu. But it is required to make the header visible and persistent.
How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am having the same issue and would appreciate any hints you may have.

Comment: No, I couldn't figure it out. Without digging into jqery code I believe that persistent toolbar is intended to work with navbar only. I'm successful with a navbar but it takes too much space when there's 7-8 item in the menu.

Comment: (Ops, enter sent the previous comment accidentally). So when there's 7-8 item the navbar is too tall that's why I changed it to selectmenu. Finally I decided to completely ignore jquery mobile page changing mechanism based on the #. I don't really like it anyway, I think it has as more disadvantage than advantage. However, JQM is really good at visual layer, it has nice widgets, easy page arranging, etc. That saves a lot of time. And that's just a few lines to do something ajax like stuff by yourself that asks for a page and replaces the main content with a $.html() call.